# How to change error messages returned in composer-rest-server?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

In the smart contracts, I have added a few checks, ex:

```
      // Check if user owns the property
  if(submittedOwnerId !== actualOwnerId){
    // If they are not the owner, give error and quit
    throw new Error('You do not own this property'); 
  }
```

In the Composer Playground the errors are being returned like this:

```
Error: You do not own this property
```

But in composer-rest-server, the errors are being returned like this:
[image: Error currently being returned:]

I am wondering if there is a setting in composer-rest-server where I can simply only return the actual error message, like how it is returned in Composer Playground.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to alter the message returned in composer-rest-server via a setting. The reason you are seeing such a simple output in composer-playground is because you are using the web browser connector which provides a simulation of a very simple environment and thus the code path is different to connecting to a real fabric either through playground or the rest server. If you used playground to connect to a real fabric then you would see a similar message to that of composer-rest-server.